# vim on Rnw (sweave) files: how to indent <<>>= properly?

Tags: vim, indentation, sweave

(This question is close to one [I posted yesterday on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/vim-on-rnw-sweave-files-how-to-indent-properly), but I have come to realize I should have posted it here.)

When I use Vim latex-suite to indent my `.Rnw` files, the Sweave blocks (e.g. a line like `<<>>=`) get indented (if it's following indented text, e.g. in an itemized list). Unfortunately, this "breaks" the Sweave commands, because they *must* start in the first column.

I have only minimal skill with Vim, and a morning of searching has not shown me how to alter my `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim` (or other relevant) file to make Sweave blocks have zero indentation, but to have the latex code that follows be properly indented. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update to vim's R plugin now works fine, as of yesterday.